# Exporting a matplotlib animation to an image

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib animation (for instance [one of these](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)) and I want to export it to a SVG image where several frames are superimposed (e.g. in [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224673662_A_Method_for_Trajectory_Optimization_of_Robots_having_Contacts_or_Motion_Constraints/file/d912f511a55ddba62a.pdf), Fig. 2. on the 5th page). The objective is to have an image that describes the motion as clearly as possible.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't view the .pdf at the moment, but my approach to solving this would be to draw each 'frame' of the animation in the same plot in  matplotlib using `plot(x,y)`, and then use `savefig('image.svg')` (if .svg is a format that can be saved in this manner from matplotlib).

Optionally, I would add another argument to the `plot` call, which colours the plots a different shade of colour, according to the frame number.